# Field validation in WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, validation, webforms

I'm more of an MVC kind of guy and not cosy with WebForms so I hope this is not a stupid question.

Given this kind of code

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="requiredLoanType" runat="server" InitialValue="default" ControlToValidate="loanTypeList" 
     ErrorMessage="* Required information" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="addCommitmentDetails" CssClass="errorText" 
     SetFocusOnError="true" />
```

Is it possible for me to modify the validation given the state of another field on the page? That is to say how would I apply the validation sometimes and not others?

Hope that is reasonably clear.

Comment: Sorry all, I tagged it wrong, should be WebForms, oops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope i understood what you want

You can enable and disable the Validator in your code behind(Server Side) in case it is a Web form application based on your condition.

```
requiredLoanType.Enabled = false/true;
```

Also this can be achieved in javascript on the Client Side

```
var validator = document.getElementById("<%=requiredLoanType.ClientID %>");
ValidatorEnable(validator, true/false);
```